# How to traverse all the elements in a STL (like unordered_set) while deleting them

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I have written an example code:

```
void eg(){
  unordered_set<int> s;
  s.insert(1);
  s.insert(4);
  s.insert(3);
  s.insert(6);
  auto ite = s.begin();
  while(ite != s.end()){
    int num = *ite;
    cout << num << endl;
    while(s.find(num+1) != s.end()){
      s.erase(s.find(num));
      num++;
    }
    while(s.find(num-1) != s.end()){
      s.erase(s.find(num));
      num--;
    }
    auto tmp = ite;
    ite ++;
    s.erase(tmp);
  }
}
```

So basically it creates a set and adds {1,3,4,6} in it. It traverse the set and print the element, after printing it deletes all the consecutive elements in the set.

So the code is supposed to print something like 1,x(one of 3 and 4, because the other will be erased),6.

But after I run it, it printed 3 and segmentation fault.
How could I erase the elements and at the same time keep the iterator valid?

I'm getting my english improved.

Thank you all for help!

Comment: When `num` is 3, `ite` is already invalidated when you get to `auto tmp = ite;` because you erased the element it points to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erase [returns](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/erase) an iterator following the last removed element, so just replace

```
s.erase(.....);
```

with

```
ite = s.erase(.....);
```

everywhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the iterator returned by [std::set::erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase).

```
ite = s.erase(...);
```